# How can I type in a specific width for my browser? I am using Chrome and the inspect element

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to type in a width value for the screen size so I can make proper break points. I often find myself trying to inch one pixel at a time from on size to another. This isn't always successful in Chrome, as I sometimes go by two pixels at a time. Is there a way to make the width a specific typed in width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chrome 38 (Canary as of now), you have the awesome `Device mode` (Button 1 in the picture), and once the device emulation UI appears, you have the awesome `Media queries` debugger (Button 2 in the picture), which helps you debug your media queries breakpoints.

If the device presets are not enough for you, the page view is drag-resizable, and with your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down, you can be VERY precise.

[image: Meida query breakpoints debugger]